# How to search a large number of tweets

Tags: r, text-mining, twitter-search

I want to search for 50 keywords on twitter. So far, I have tried two methods for searching Twitter. The first method only prints the last tweets's data for me regardless of keywords.

This is first method I used:

```
for (i in c("#GMCR","#NFLX","#PCLN","#SWN","#MA","#EW","#WDC", "#ROST", "#RHT", "#ESRX", "#URBN", "#CRM", "#THC", "#BLK", "#AMZN", "#AAPL", "#CERN", "#FFIV", "#DTV", "#AZO", "#ISRG", "#SJM", "#EOG", "#OXY", "#CF", "#GIS", "#FLS", "#WMT", "#NTAP", "#HSP", "#CSX", "#ACT", "#MOS", "#TJX", "#CL", "#MCD", "#COG", "#RRC", "#FLIR", "#CTSH", "#MYL", "#LEG", "#APH", "#VAR", "#HAS", "#FSLR", "#APA", "#ABC", "#UNP", "#EL"))
         {
           tweet6<-searchTwitter(i,lang='en',since='2015-09-02', until='2015-09-03')
         }
tweet6
```

This is second method, i just put 50 keywords in the `searchTwitter()` function, but it give a 403 error:

```
tweet6<-searchTwitter('#GMCR||#NFLX||#PCLN||#SWN||#MA||#EW||#WDC||#ROST||#RHT||#ESRX||#URBN||#CRM||#THC||#BLK||#AMZN||#AAPL||#CERN||#FFIV||#DTV||#AZO||#ISRG||#SJM||#EOG||#OXY||#CF||#GIS||#FLS||#WMT||#NTAP||#HSP||#CSX||#ACT||#MOS||#TJX||#CL||#MCD||#COG||#RRC||#FLIR||#CTSH||#MYL||#LEG||#APH||#VAR||#HAS||#FSLR||#APA||#ABC||#UNP||#EL',
n=500,lang='en,since='2015-09-02', until='2015-09-03')
```

This returns:

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, "GET", ...) : 
  client error: (403) Forbidden
```

Comment: Aren't hastags for stocks, called `cashtags` so `#GMCR` would be `$GMCR` ? @DougwenKuei

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [twitter API documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search). Under best practices in search:

> Limit
> your searches to 10 keywords and operators.
>
> Queries can be limited due
> to complexity. If this happens the Search API will respond with the
> error: {"error":"Sorry, your query is too complex. Please reduce
> complexity and try again."}

So, you can search up to 10 at once. You should not use pipes in your search, the correct way to search for mutliple keywords is just a space:

```
searchTwitter('#GMCR #NFLX #PCLN ...)
```

I think your loop is the best way of going about this, just make sure you don;t hit the rate limit:

> The GET search/tweets is part of the Twitter REST API 1.1 and is rate
> limited similarly to other v1.1 methods. See REST API Rate Limiting in
> v1.1 for information on that model. At this time, users represented by
> access tokens can make 180 requests/queries per 15 minutes. Using
> application-only auth, an application can make 450 queries/requests
> per 15 minutes on its own behalf without a user context.